# Is calling functions from other functions or as a parameter to an array a good/bad practice?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Let's say I've objects A and B.

Is it a good practice to call functions/parameters like this:

`A[B->getValue()].setValue(C.getValue() + 10);`

Consider all the required assumptions like A is an array, B is object pointer, C is an object, setValue and getValue are methods of that class etc.

The only gist of this question is if calling functions like that is good?
Or should it be more like:

```
Temp1 = b->getValue();
Temp2 = c.getValue();
A[Temp1].setValue(Temp2 + 10);
```

Comment: Consider posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: seems like a question better suited for codereview, personally I find it bad practice since part because it gets less readable and part that you cannot handle invalid return values

Comment: It's all about readability!

Comment: Before posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, remember to go through that site's posting guidelines. Snippets of code will be closed down quickly.

Comment: It's not suitable for codereview either - generally this is an opinion based question. Some people like the terse first line, some people line the second approach - use what works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of

```
Temp1 = B->getValue();
Temp2 = C.getValue();
A[Temp1].setValue(Temp2 + 10);
```

is good for debugging. Once you have debugged the code, it is better to use:

```
A[B->getValue()].setValue(C.getValue() + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using *anonymous temporaries* which is what the statement `A[B->getValue()].setValue(C.getValue() + 10);` is doing. As well as finding it clearer, I prefer this since it prevents leaking too many variables into scope.

Note that the C++ standard allows anonymous temporaries to be passed to function arguments that are `const` references.